# same flutter project but different git repository

Tags: git, flutter, dart

I have the same flutter project but I want two different apps from the same project because the client wants some minor changes but the other client didn’t. Also, both client wants their specific apps on the play store and app store as well and requested code as well. I want to copy my existing project so I can match the second client's requirements without doing any changes to the first one. can I be able to change the project origin URL to the new one?

Comment: Why don't you create different branch for the other client?

Comment: I also suggest to keep same repository but different branch

Comment: But the client wants to use his own repo

Answer (score 1):

You can link the same project to two different repositories and push to or pull from anyone you want at any time.

```
git remote add remoteOne <repository address 1>

git remote add remoteTwo <repository address 2>
```

So, as you proceed, you can do `git push remoteOne` or `git push remotewo`  after you commit your progress